# Extend promise while resolving

Tags: javascript, promise

I tried to extend a promise while its resolution is ongoing.

```js
(async () => {
  var p4 = Promise.resolve([3]);
  var rec = (s) => {
    let x = s.pop();
    s.push(x - 1);
    if (x > 0) {
      console.log(x);
      p4.then(rec);
    }
  };
  p4.then(rec);
  console.log("result", (await p4)[0]);
})();
```

My problem is: the recursion works as expected (3, 2, 1 is printed), but the result is 2 instead of 0. It seems to me that the last line just sees the first step of the recursion. It follows only those continuations, which have been added till the resolution starts. Those which are added while the resolution is ongoing are ignored. How to fix this?

Comment: It's logging 2 because of the timing: you only told it to `await p4`, not to await any promises chained off of p4. So it's going to log before those last two promises have resolved. Maybe you could create an array of each of the promises you create, and then await them all? Would that meet your needs?

Comment: For clarity: `.then()` does not modify the target Promise; it creates a new, semi-independent Promise. (I say semi-independent because it is a new Promise created using one of the given callbacks, but when that happens and which callback is used depend on when and how the "parent" Promise settles.)

Comment: On the same line, you are not creating a chain of Promises by calling `.then()` recursively; you are actually attaching all those callbacks in parallel. You can instead mutate `p4` to always point at the latest Promise, in the style of a `.reduce()` accumulator: `p4 = p4.then(rec)`

Comment: @DarrylNoakes Modifying the global variable of the promise does not seem to help.

Answer (score 1):

`p4` and `p4.then` are different promises, since `then()` returns a new promise. Use `then()` together with `await` to wait for your `then` chain resolution.

Also you should return from `rec()` either a chained promise created again with `p4.then()` or `[0]` as the final chain result. Otherwise your promise is resolved immediately without chaining.

Also when you chain promise you shouldn't decrement the array element, otherwise you will get `result -1`.

```js
(async () => {
  var p4 = Promise.resolve([3]);
  var rec = (s) => {
    if (s[0] > 0) {
      let x = s.pop();
      s.push(x - 1);
      console.log(x);
      return p4.then(rec);
    }
    return s;
  };

  console.log("result", (await p4.then(rec))[0]);
})();
```

We can simplify the code:

```js
(async () => {
  var p4 = Promise.resolve([3]);
  var rec = s => s[0] ? console.log(s[0]) ?? (s[0]--, p4.then(rec)) : s;

  console.log("result", (await p4.then(rec))[0]);
})();
```

Comment: This seems to decrement 4 times, because `s` is `[-1]` in the end. You have cheated by returning `[0]` instead of `s`.

Comment: @ceving fixed the code, added explanation and a simplified one-liner

Comment: So instead of returning my stack, I have to return the new promise created by `then`. I think I found the relevant description in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then): *"If the handler function returns another pending promise: p is pending and becomes fulfilled/rejected with that promise's value as its value immediately after that promise becomes fulfilled/rejected."*

Comment: @ceving in your case the promise is already resolved (`Promise.resolve([3])`), so it's *returns an already fulfilled promise: p gets fulfilled with that promise's value as its value.*

Comment: MDN says: *"`then` Returns a new Promise immediately. This new promise is always pending when returned, regardless of the current promise's status."*

Comment: @ceving not sure it's correct, in the console `Promise.resolve([3]).then(s => s)` gives a fulfilled promise

Comment: @ceving `new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(()=>resolve([3]), 1000)).then(x => x);` will give a pending promise. I guess `This new promise is always pending when returned` means the callback will be called async. Actually it's strange, maybe I don't understand how the console works with promises

Answer (score 0):

Instead of working with `Promise` manually, try using `async` and `await` like this:

```js
async function rec(s) {
    let x = s.pop();
    s.push(x - 1);
    if (x > 0) {
        console.log(x);
        return await rec(s);
    } else return s;
}
console.log("result", (await rec([3]))[0]);
// 3
// 2
// 1
// result -1
```

Stackless version:

```js
async function rec(s) {
    for (;;) {
        let x = s.pop();
        s.push(x - 1);
        if (x > 0) console.log(x);
        else return s;
    }
}
console.log("result", (await rec([3]))[0]);
```

The snippets refuse to run, but I promise it works in a browser console.